# Script error's from not debugging

Tags: html

Keep getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null main.js:24
makingMySelect main.js:24
(anonymous function)
here's the code:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

function $(x){
    var myElements = document.getElementById(x);
    return myElements;
}
// create select field element and populate with options
function makingMySelect (){
    var formTag = document.getElementsByTagName("form");// array
    var selectLi = $("select");
    var makeSelect = document.createElement("select");
        makeSelect.setAttribute("id","peopleGoing");
    for(i=0,j=reservePeopleGoing.length;i<j;i++){
        var makeOption = document.createElement("option");
        var optText = reservePeopleGoing[i];
        makeOption.setAttribute("value", optText);
        makeOption.innerHTML = optText;
        makeSelect.appendChild(makeOption);
    }
    selectLi.appendChild(makeSelect);
}


var reservePeopleGoing = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var placeToGo = ["Astrada's","AppleBees","Chili's","Outback","O'Charleys"]
makingMySelect ();
```

Comment: You need to debug your code.

Comment: agree with @SLaks need to debug, if you are getting error, it must be telling you where you are getting error and that is the key to solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: `var myElements = document.getElementById(x);` myElements when selecting an id? Better use myElement

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I can not use jQuery;

Comment: Okay. Fine. Ignore the jQuery part. :)

Comment: the reason I used myElements is that it is an array;

Comment: I guess it's saying my selectLi is null? tried to fix with Praveen answer but still get that it is null

Comment: @BrianStacks Just try to remove the `!` in my answer. It is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a check before you do this part:

```
if (selectLi)
    selectLi.appendChild(makeSelect);
```

So, this checks whether `selectLi` is already good. Then adds the stuff. Also, are you sure have an element with `ID` as `select`? Don't get confused between tagname. :)

---

**Working HTML Code**

The issue was you didn't have an element with an `id` of `select`. So, I just added this code:

```
<div id="select"></div>
```

After the registration link and it works. Enjoy. Full code for your reference.

```
<!doctype html>
<html manifest="/cache.manifest">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta keywords="Reserve,resteraunt,hotel" />
        <meta description="This app will let you reserve a spot at your favorite location" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi-dpi" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>Make My Reservation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>My Reservation App</h1>
                <p>This app will let you make a reservation! </p>
            </div>
        </header>
        <h3>Ready?</h3>
        <p><a href= "addItem.html">Add A Reservation</a></p>
        <div id="select"></div>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <img src="img/Reservation_app_img.jpg"width= "100" height="100" title="Reservation Logo" />
        <p1>6-3-2013, Brian Stacks</p1>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess it's saying my selectLi is null? tried to fix with Praveen answer but still get that it is null

Comment: @BrianStacks Can you please make us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the whole script?

Comment: Should I check `index.html`?

Comment: Check @BrianStacks, Removing the `!` should work now. See the updated answer. :)

Comment: @ Praveen Thank you that got rid of my error, But it did not create my dropdown list for me? Thanks a million!

Comment: Okay... Lemme check your script once again. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Buddy, your `index.html` doesn't have anything with a ID of `select`.

Comment: And what's the `<p1>` tag for?

Comment: it was a mispelling in my HTML index file.. Thank you geniuses for your help!! Love all yaw!!

Comment: Hello all this was a project for school, I didn't do my due diligence and debug as said earlier in the post. @Praveen Kumar was correct, didn't have the correct id's for my code to work.Again this could have been accomplished by debugging my code!